# java.lang.NullPointerException al asignar valor de variable a objeto

Tags: nullpointerexception

Agradeceria, por favor, si alguien puede decirme por favor porque en la linea: p1.setNombre(cadena);

de este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File archivo;
    FileReader  lector;
    pelicula p1 =  null;
    String cadena = "", nombre = "", genero="";
    int duracion, puntuacion;
    float c;
    archivo = new File("pelis.txt");
    lector = new FileReader(archivo);
    try (BufferedReader almacen = new BufferedReader(lector)){
     while (cadena != null){
            cadena = almacen.readLine();
            p1.setNombre(cadena);
            cadena = almacen.readLine();
            p1.setGenero(cadena);
            cadena = almacen.readLine();
            duracion = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            p1.setDuracion(duracion);
            cadena = almacen.readLine();
            puntuacion = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            p1.setPuntuacion(puntuacion);
            if (cadena != null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1.getPelicula());
            }                   
    }
try {
        almacen.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Algo malo ha sucedido");
    }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problema encontrando el archivo");
    }
    }
}
```

Se me presenta un java.lang.NullPointerException??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error se te presenta debido a que no has creado una instancia de la clase película

```
File archivo;
FileReader  lector;
pelicula p1 =  null;
```

En este punto la variable p1 esta nula, deberías tener algo así:

```
File archivo;
FileReader  lector;
pelicula p1 = new pelicula();
```

ya con esto a la variable p1 se le esta asignando un espacio de memoria en el cual guardar información.